# how to compile a C code to call an octave function and make the GUI using GTK+2

Tags: application-development, gtk, c, octave

i am trying to call a octave function from C code but the problem is that when why run this command in octave `mkoctfile --mex addition_GUI.c` error occurs `addition_GUI.c:1:20: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
mxArray *in[2], *out[1];

in[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(1);
in[1] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(2);

mexCallMATLAB(1, out, 2, in, "addition");
mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 1, out, "disp");

mxDestroyArray(in[0]);
mxDestroyArray(in[1]);
mxDestroyArray(out[0]);
}
void static call(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data)
{
g_print("\n%s\n",gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(data)));
gint a=3;
gint b=2;
gint x;
x=a+b;
char y[4]; 
    sprintf(y, "%d", x);
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(data),y); 
}

    int main(int agrc, char *agrv[])

{
gtk_init(&agrc,&agrv);
GtkWidget *entry,*window,*button,*hbox;

window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);

hbox=gtk_hbox_new(0,0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),hbox);
button=gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("ADD");
entry=gtk_entry_new();
const char* sum="3+2";
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry),sum); 
g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),entry);
g_signal_connect(entry,"activate",G_CALLBACK(call),entry);



gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),button,0,0,0);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),entry,0,0,0);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the necessary gtk+ header search path(s) on the `mkoctfile` command line?

```
OPTIONS
       mkoctfile accepts the following options:

       -IDIR   Add include directory DIR to compile commands.
```

You should be able to use the `pkg-config` utility to include all the header directories automatically e.g.

```
mkoctfile `pkg-config --cflags-only-I gtk+-2.0` --mex addition_GUI.c
```

Alternatively, you could run

```
pkg-config --cflags-only-I gtk+-2.0
```

on the command line and manually copy the include paths that it outputs to your mkoctfile command. You will need both the `pkg-config` package and the development files and headers for gtk+-2.0 i.e. the `libgtk2.0-dev` package installed on your system.

In order to create a runable mex executable you will probably need to add the corresponding libraries using the mkoctfile `-L` option - or by adding `--libs` to the `pkg-config` command i.e.

```
mkoctfile `pkg-config --cflags-only-I --libs gtk+-2.0` --mex addition_GUI.c
```

or (to add libraries manually)

```
pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
```

Comment: i have tried it and now the error is `sh: 1: pkg-config --cflags-only-I gtk+-2.0: not found
mkoctfile: unrecognized argument`

Comment: Make sure you are using backticks around the pkg-config command - not regular single quotes. If in doubt, copy and paste the whole command.

Comment: i did copy paste it.i am using backticks. i have compiled it on gcc compiler i know about backticks

Comment: i have used ``mkoctfile `pkg-config --cflags-only-I gtk+-2.0` --mex addition_GUI.c`` but i am getting error `sh: 1: pkg-config --cflags-only-I gtk+-2.0: not found mkoctfile: unrecognized argument`

Comment: Sorry I am unable to reproduce that error message - however I have updated my answer with a suggestion of how to manually add the necessary `-I` include directories

Comment: here is the path `-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12` how to copy these paths to mkoctfile command??

Comment: i have tried this and successfully compiled the code but when i try to run it gives error. command is `mkoctfile -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 --mex addition_GUI.c` and when i try to run addition_GUI it gives error  `undefined symbol: gtk_main_quit` how to add libraries???

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: i used this command ``mkoctfile `pkg-config --cflags-only-I --libs gtk+-2.0` --mex addition_GUI.c ``in terminal and it compiled successfully . when i used command `addition_GUI` in octave terminal the result is `octave-3.2.4:7> addition_GUI`
`warning:   addition_GUI`
 `7` and the GUI also didn't opened itself and answer should be `3` not `7`. Although there is a GUI executable file there which display a text box when i opens it but it doesn't open itself as it should open by it self when i give the command addition_GUI in octave console

Comment: I suggest you start another question about the runtime errors - they are not really related to your original "how to compile..." question